# Changing multiple colnames simultaneously replacing data with NA

Tags: r

I'm trying to rename multiple column names of a data frame  in which the columns contain more than a single type, the columns are a factor class.

```
col1 col2 col3  col4 col5  col6
a    b     c    a     b    a
1    5     8    2     2   5
```

conditional on an entry in a row:

```
colnames(df)[which(df[1,]=="b " )]<-"new_colname"
```

Ideally producing something like:

```
col1 new_colname col3  col4 new_colname.2 col6
a      b           c    a       b        a
1      5           8    2       2        5
```

But when I do this all the columns that are renamed have their data replaced with NAs, producing:

```
col1 col2 col3
NA    NA    NA
NA   NA    NA
```

Does anyone know why this would happen?

The

Comment: Try to convert the `factor` class to `character` and rename. i.e. `df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)` if all the columns are factor.  Also, if the condition gives TRUE for more than one column, then you might have duplicate column names.

Comment: @akrun Still had the same problem after converting the classes.

Comment: Could you show the code used and the error message?

Comment: @akrun There is no error it just turns everything in the renamed columns into NA, the code in the question is exactly as I wrote it into R.

Comment: Could you update the post with the expected result and also make your example reproducible rather than `which(df[1,]=="string" )`

Comment: The data.table package authors say that changing names copies the entire object. You could avoid that using the `setnames` function from their package. The function does not need to be applied to data.tables. For example: `mydf <- data.frame(1); str(mydf); setnames(mydf,'bah'); str(mydf)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, the dataset columns are all "factor" class, convert the columns to "character" class.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
```

In case, there are leading/lagging spaces, use `str_trim` to remove those spaces,

```
library(stringr)
df[] <- lapply(df, str_trim)
```

Change the column names based on the conditions mentioned, and use `make.names` for creating unique names for those duplicated column names.

```
names(df)[df[1,]=='b'] <- 'new_colname'
names(df) <- make.names(names(df), unique=TRUE)
df
#  col1 new_colname col3 col4 new_colname.1 col6
#1    a           b    c    a             b    a
#2    1           5    8    2             2    5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "a"
), class = "factor"), col2 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("5", 
"b"), class = "factor"), col3 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("8", 
"c"), class = "factor"), col4 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("2", 
"a"), class = "factor"), col5 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("2", 
"b"), class = "factor"), col6 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("5", 
"a"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3",  
"col4", "col5", "col6"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end fixed this by naming them using a different method, using a for loop:

```
for(i in 1:length(df)){colnames(df)[i]<-paste("df", df[1,i],df[3,i],  eval(i) ,sep="_" )}
```

This would probably not be feasible for an extremely large dataset, so if anyone knows how one might do this another way please post an answer.

Comment: Based on the data showed in the post (character columns), after applying this code, `colnames(df)#
[1] "df_a_NA_1" "df_b_NA_2" "df_c_NA_3"`